# Using Nginx as Webserver and Reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup Nginx as a reverse proxy and webserver together. and I'm having issues in trying to understand how I can do it.

Let's assume I am using the default Symfony2 nginx configuration
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html):

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

I want to add a configuration so the Nginx will also function as a reverse proxy. and not only a webserver.

1. Do I need to add to the same configuration file the `proxy_pass`, `proxy_cache`, etc.. configurations?
2. Do I need to set a configuration for a specific routes? or to disable them?
3. If for example if I don't want the route `/app_dev.php/abc` to be cached? what do I need to do?

Comment: Add an `upstream` block for the destination you want to forward to, then add a second `server` block with the proxy configuration inside (the minimal config is `location / { proxy_pass http://<upstream_block_name>; }`.

Comment: but this configuration is my Webserver as well.. so what do you mean by redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically nginx is proxy server. Its capabilities include proxy HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, POP3, SMTP and other protocols. For HTTP(S) proxy, the backend can be either FastCGI server like PHP-FPM or another web server.

For FastCGI backend like you need [fastcgi module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html). For example, you need to define the backend with `fastcgi_pass`. For proxying another website, you need [HTTP proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). You need to use direction like `proxy_pass`, `proxy_cache` to control the behaviour of this module.

> 1. Do I need to add to the same configuration file the proxy_pass, proxy_cache, etc.. configurations?

YES

> 2. Do I need to set a configuration for a specific routes? or to disable them?

For example, you need proxy the the specific URL `www.example.com/myawesomeapp`, then use location to match the URL

```
location /myawesomeapp {
    proxy_pass http://<upstream_block_name>;
    ... other parameter ...;
}
```

> 3. If for example if I don't want the route /app_dev.php/abc to be cached? what do I need to do?

Use [proxy_cache_bypass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_bypass). You can set by `if` directive like [this tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140618074009-3877069-how-to-use-nginx-cache-to-speed-up-your-website).